# Problema de acentuação em texto retornado por arquivo Javascript

Tags: javascript, formulário, utf-8, acentuação

Boa noite pessoal
Iniciando estudos de javascript fiz um código js que constitui um sistema de controle de convidados para uma festa.
O convidado informa seu nome e o nome de quem convidou ele num formulário html/css
Se seu nome está na lista de convidados do dono e ele informou o nome do dono da festa corretamente o javascript devolve no formulário html "Você pode entrar" e caso contrário "Você não pode entrar"
O problema é que essas duas mensagens estão dentro do JS e estão vindo com a acentuação desconfigurada.
No HTML eu coloquei a Tag  e para todo formulário html resolveu apenas não para essas duas frase que vem do JS. Botei ut8 até no link pra JS  e não resolveu. Vou postar o código abaixo:

```js
function VerificarEntrada() {
    NomeConvidado = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    convidadoPor = document.getElementById('convidadoPor').value;
    dono = 'Cristian';
    ConvidadosCristian = ['Amanda', 'Sabrina', 'Rafael', 'Jonas', 'Carol', 'Jhonatan'];
    if (ConvidadosCristian.includes(NomeConvidado) && convidadoPor === dono){
        document.getElementById('PermissaoDeEntrada').innerText = 'Você pode entrar';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('PermissaoDeEntrada').innerText = 'Você não pode entrar'
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistema de convites Festa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="./js/sistemaConvitesFesta.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="contact">
            <h3>Verifique se você foi convidado e pode entrar</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <input id="nome" tabindex="1" type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu nome:" required autofocus>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input id="convidadoPor" tabindex="2" type="text" placeholder="Quem convidou você?" required>
            </fieldset>    
            
            <fieldset>
                <button onclick="VerificarEntrada()" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Verificar</button>
            </fieldset>
            
            <h4>Você está permitido entrar?</h4>
            <label for="" id='PermissaoDeEntrada' >Pesquisando...</label>
        </div>
    </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, Rafael.

Testei seu código e **não aparenta ter problema algum.**

[image: Acentuação funcional.]

Que browser você está usando? Já tentou limpar a cache? *Refresh & Limpar Cache -> Cntrl+F5*

Se o problema persistir, tente utilizar o seguinte javascript:

```js
function VerificarEntrada() {
    NomeConvidado = document.getElementById('nome').value;
    convidadoPor = document.getElementById('convidadoPor').value;
    dono = 'Cristian';
    ConvidadosCristian = ['Amanda', 'Sabrina', 'Rafael', 'Jonas', 'Carol', 'Jhonatan'];
    if (ConvidadosCristian.includes(NomeConvidado) && convidadoPor === dono){
        document.getElementById('PermissaoDeEntrada').innerHTML = 'Você pode entrar';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('PermissaoDeEntrada').innerHTML = 'Você não pode entrar'
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sistema de convites Festa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <script src="./js/sistemaConvitesFesta.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="contact">
            <h3>Verifique se você foi convidado e pode entrar</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <input id="nome" tabindex="1" type="text" placeholder="Digite o seu nome:" required autofocus>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input id="convidadoPor" tabindex="2" type="text" placeholder="Quem convidou você?" required>
            </fieldset>    
            
            <fieldset>
                <button onclick="VerificarEntrada()" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Verificar</button>
            </fieldset>
            
            <h4>Você está permitido entrar?</h4>
            <label for="" id='PermissaoDeEntrada' >Pesquisando...</label>
        </div>
    </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou testar